# telethon auto reply messages

Tags: python, telethon

i need to write code that will read messages from user and reply but i’ve got to use exactly this function: GetDialogs Request, not event method. please help, can't find any information about it

Comment: Can you show use what you've tried?

Answer (score 1):

The request you mention, [`GetDialogsRequest`](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/messages/get_dialogs.html), is part of what's known as ["raw API"](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/full-api.html). Both pages of the documentation contain examples. However, as noted in the first link, you probably want to use [`client.iter_dialogs`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.dialogs.DialogMethods.iter_dialogs) (the link again contains an example):

```py
# Print all dialog IDs and the title, nicely formatted
async for dialog in client.iter_dialogs():
    print('{:>14}: {}'.format(dialog.id, dialog.title))
```

This may not be the request you're looking for though, as this returns a list of open conversations. [Following the documentation](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/) would be a good way to understand what's happening and what you should use.